# Is there a way to point a vector<double>* to a vector<int>?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two sets, one containing `vector<int>` and the other `vector<double>` instances. I only need to remember one among all of these instances for further processing depending on some criteria. Conceptually, the idea is simple:

```
vectorOfInterest *v;

for (i : set<vector<double>>)
    if criteria_met(i)
    {
        *v = &i,
        break;
    }

for (i : set<vector<int>>)
    if criteria_met(i)
    {
        *v = &i,
        break;
    }

// Do something with *v later.
```

Note that *set* here is used conceptually and doesn't refer literally to `std::set`. I can only use *v at the end for further processing and not immediately when it is found because the processing logic depends on various other steps that happen after the last loop, and cannot be evaluated in advance.

Currently, my approach is to use a void pointer and later cast it to the appropriate type depending on which of the two sets the vector of interest was found in:

```
void* vectorOfInterest;

if (vectorOfInterest found within set<vector<double>>)
{
    auto v = static_cast<std::vector<double>*>(vectorOfInterest);
    // do something with v
}
else if (vectorOfInterest found within set<vector<int>>)
{
    auto v = static_cast<std::vector<int>*>(vectorOfInterest);
    // do something with v
}
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if there's a better way in C++ to achieve this, perhaps one without using void pointers and casting? For example, something along the lines of this:

```
std::vector<double>* vectorOfInterest;

for (i : set<vector<double>>)
    if criteria_met(i)
    {
        vectorOfInterest = &i;
        break;
    }

for (i : set<vector<int>>)
    if criteria_met(i)
    {
        vectorOfInterest = &i; // Obviously this won't compile.
        break;
    }

// Do something with vectorOfInterest directly, without needing a cast.
```

I *assume* that the answer is that there is no direct way to get this behavior as `vector<double>*` is fundamentally different from `vector<int>*`, but wanted to second-check this assumption. Is my original approach of using a void pointer indeed the proper way here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186683/discussion-on-question-by-w128-is-there-a-way-to-point-a-vectordouble-to-a-ve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't.

Unlike Java generics for example, a `std::vector<double>` is a completely different type to a `std::vector<int>`, so if you were to attempt to convert a pointer to one into the other type, the behaviour of the program is undefined due to *strict aliasing* violation.

The only thing you can do, aside from working with a consistent type from the get-go, is to perform an element-by-element copy into the type you want.

Comment: "_behaviour of the program is undefined due to strict aliasing violation._" no it's undefined because there is nothing to define it so even in C++-=1 which is C++ without type based aliasing rules (which are a mess) it wouldn't be define

Answer (score 2):

Edit for the new version of the question: `variant<vector<int>*, vector<double>*>` may be useful to your use case.

There is no "right" approach of casting a `std::vector<double>*` to a `std::vector<int>*` because such pointer cannot be used for anything useful. Indirecting through the pointer would have undefined behaviour.

That said, `reinterpret_cast` of a data pointer is equivalent to conversion to `void*` and then `static_cast` to another pointer type. But as pointed out, that's not useful here.

Comment: Yes but at least `reinterpret_cast` implies that interpretation of an object as another type will occur later (probably). `static_cast` implies no such thing, that could be the inverse of a conversion to `void*`; thus `static_cast` is potentially misleading.

Comment: @curiousguy One of the safer uses of `reinterpret_cast` is to cast *back* to the original type later. In my experience it's by far the most common use of `reinterpret_cast` which is contrary to implying that the intermediate "interpretation" will be dereferenced. Though our experiences might differ.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Note that there is no "universal type", no `void*` for function pointers. That means that people use a pseudo function pointer `void*` type, with arbitrary but meaningless argument list (of course unlike the true `void*` type, that function type is usable by accident: it's callable). So of course when a function pointer type is stored, `reinterpret_cast` is used. But it's by lack of a `static_cast` syntax.

Comment: @curiousguy Function pointers are a whole other thing. I'm not sure where they entered into this discussion, I guess I missed it. My comment is only talking about type punning and presenting my experiences as a counter pointer of view to your proposition.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `variant`, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Function pointers entered the discussion via your remark about use of `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast`.